# Sort by Postcode depending user input

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to sort by postcode, if user type in: L25

The result may look something like this:

- L12
- L24
- L25
- L21
- L22
- L25

I want user input 'L25' to appear at the top and then sort the rest?

Example:

- L25
- L25
- L12
- L21
- L22
- L24

Is that possible by SQL Query?

Comment: Why do it in a SQL query? You're just making life hard for yourself. Do it in your application logic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select MyColumn 
from MyTable
order by case when MyColumn = 'L25' then 0 else 1 end,
    MyColumn
```

Comment: I'm afraid this is not going to work, because SQL will be trying to convert the string 'L25' to int, which will cause an error. However, I use SQL server, not mysql, so maybe I am not aware of some differences...

Comment: @Helena, no - it is comparing L25 with MyColumn, which is a string, not an Int. (British postcodes are characters - eg. L25 1AA - not purely numeric codes like American Zipcodes.)

Comment: Yes Mark, you are right. I wanted to edit the comment, but I already had to delete it whole & repost... Sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do the job:

```
SELECT * 
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN postcode LIKE @userinput THEN ''
    ELSE postcode END
```